# Prove Identity involving logarithms and exponents

Tags: logarithms

Can you give me some hints on how to solve the following identity? $a^{\ln(n)} = n^{\ln(a)}$

Comment: The easiest way is using the injectivity of $\ln$ and applying it to both sides of the equation

Answer (score 1):

$\ln a \ln n=\ln n \ln a \implies \ln n^{\ln a}=\ln a^{\ln n}$ (since $\ln a^b=b\ln a$)

Now by the injectivity of $\ln$ (i.e. because it is strictly increasing) so $n^{\ln a}=a^{\ln n}$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use that

$$\log n=\frac{\log_a n}{\log_a e}$$

therefore

$$a^{\log n}=a^{\frac{\log_a n}{\log_a e}}=(a^{\log_a n})^{\frac1{\log_a e}}=\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b,c >0$, then the general result is
$$a^{\log_{~b} c}= c^{\log_{~b} a}.~~~(1)$$
You may prove (1) by taking $\log$ on both w.r.t. and unknown base we get.
$$ \log_{b} c ~\log a = \log_{~b}  a ~ \log c$$ this is nothing but
$$\frac{\log c}{\log b} \log a= \frac{\log a}{\log b} \log c,$$ Hence (1) is proved.

Note: it is known that $$\log_{~q}~ p= \frac{\log_{~r} p}{\log_{~r}~ q}$$

Comment: Thanks to all for the hints. I got the result using these hints.

Comment: @Baljeet Now, you may give upvote(s) and accept an answer.